# ADF, jsf components do not show in Palette in Eclipse

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, palette

I just created a file called `test.xhtml` in Eclipse, but the Palette only show HTML4.0, no JSF or ADF components.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you created a web application project. Choose File --> New --> ADF Application from the menu. This will set up your project for JSF and ADF Faces